# SQL Trace log showing Revoke Execute from SQLArcExtensionUserRole

Tags: log, trace

Every hour, the SQL trace log gets a dump of all databases getting their Server side Permissions altered, this is the exact text - ALTER ROLE db_backupoperator DROP MEMBER "SQLArcExtensionUserRole"
also REVOKE EXECUTE FROM "SQLArcExtensionUserRole" and REVOKE SELECT FROM "SQLArcExtensionUserRole";. What is causing this? I dont have any jobs that run this kind of request.

Comment: afaik, there supposed to be a job that triggers every hour to do that, If you happen to see those log entries, it indicates Azure Arc Agent for SQL Server is working as intended. The access must be temporarily revoked before re-granting it so that the Azure Arc Agent can perform its operations. What is the frequency for those errors you are seeing?

Comment: This happens every hour, so I agree its some kind of a job, but what runs it? I don't see anything in the agent jobs also I don't have Azure integration. its as if a windows update occurred and this job just appeared and started to run.

Answer (score 0):

Found our culprit, our Parent company created Windows Task Scheduler job, utilizing the executable "SqlServerExtensionDeployer.exe". To stop it just disable the windows task.